# how does a couchdb cluster respond when a document is not available on a node?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I have a cluster of three couchdb 2.0 nodes A (in America) B (in Europe) and C (in Asia). All of these are behind a domain (say domain.com) and I am using nginx to load balance using the GeoIP module. So for e.g. a request from Asia would be routed to the Asia node of CouchDB.

My couchdb clusters are updated independently. I know that couchDBs will have eventual consistency. But if a request for a document is routed to the Asia server and the document is not present there (yet), would the cluster search for the document in the other nodes or would it return a 404?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load balance/failover with pouchdb/couchdb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793240/how-to-load-balance-failover-with-pouchdb-couchdb)